# IncDay not increasing date variable. Date remains constant

Tags: delphi, datetime

I'm trying to increase the date in Delphi by one day per button click. I'm using the incday function.
This is my code:

```
Procedure ButtonClick
begin
IncDay(currdate,1);
ShowMessage(DateTimeToStr(currdate));
end;
```

currdate is set to "date" in another procedure.

When the procedure ButtonClick is run, the date remains as the value of the system date.

Comment: Remains, because this function returns modified input value, It doesn't modify the input parameter _in-place_. Use `CurrDate := IncDay(CurrDate);` (you can omit increment value 1 as it's default).

Comment: Learn the difference between a function and a procedure. Read the definition of `IncDay`. Or at least try reading the [IncDay documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.DateUtils.IncDay).

Comment: I can imagine that the confusion rooted from how `Inc()` works.